# chrome.action Não funciona?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Estou tentando criando uma extensão e usando como referencia a propria documentação da [Google For Develops](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/action?hl=pt-br) para isso. Porém estou enfrentando grandes problemas com o chrome.action, ele não funciona de forma alguma. O mais estranho disso é meu aquivo background.js está sendo executado e realmente é algum poroblema com chrome.action.

manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "ConnectMe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A basic boot for connection in linkdlin",
  "host_permissions":["https://*.linkedin.com/*"],
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/tres.png"
  }, 
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs", 
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://*.linkedin.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Meu arquivo background.js

```js
/* Funciona */
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.action.setBadgeText({
    text: "OFF",
  });
});


/* Não funciona */
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  console.log("chrome.action.onClicked")
  chrome.action.setBadgeText({
    text: "ON",
  });
});
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.